# Shopify Theme Development - Main Menu schema (invalid JSON in schema)

Tags: json, shopify

For the last two weeks I've been taking a Shopify theme developer course and started developing my very own theme in Shopify. However, I have encountered a couple of strange problems. I currently have a header that contains a slideshow, where I can select images from the Shopify Customizer. However, I also need to display the main menu, and this is where the problem is. I have tried to add my menu in the schema like this:

```
{% schema %}
{
    "name": "Main Menu",
    "settings": [
        {
            "type": "link_list",
            "id": "main_linklist",
            "label": "Menu",
            "default": "main-menu"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "name": "Homepage Carousel",
    "settings": [
        {
            "type": "image_picker",
            "id": "slide-1",
            "label": "Slide 1"
        },
        {
            "type": "image_picker",
            "id": "slide-2",
            "label": "Slide 2"
        }
    ]
}
{% endschema %}
```

The error that I'm getting is 'Invalid JSON in tag 'schema'. I have also tried to make to schemas, but I quickly found out that this did not work. Can anyone point me in the right direction here? It has been driving me crazy for two days now, and I honestly can't find a fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

You combining `settings_schema.json` and section `{% schema %}` logic, which is a "No no".

This is how a standard `settings_schema.json` should look like:

```
[
  {
    "name": "theme_info",
    "theme_name": "Theme",
    "theme_author": "N/A",
    "theme_version": "1.0.0",
    "theme_documentation_url": "https://help.shopify.com/manual/using-themes",
    "theme_support_email": "theme-support@shopify.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "General",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Favicon"
      },
      {
        "type": "image_picker",
        "id": "favicon",
        "label": "Favicon"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Social media",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "header",
        "content": "Social sharing image"
      },
      {
        "type": "image_picker",
        "id": "share_image",
        "label": "Image"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Footer",
    "settings": [
      {
        "type": "richtext",
        "id": "copyright",
        "label": "Copyright",
        "info": "Use [year] to set the current year."
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

And this is how should a section `{% schema %}` look like.

```
{% schema %}
  {
    "name": "Slideshow",
    "settings": [
      {
        "id": "header",
        "type": "text",
        "label": "Header",
        "default": "Hello world"
      },
      {
        "id": "content",
        "type": "textarea",
        "label": "Content"
      }
    ],
    "blocks": [
      {
        "type": "quote",
        "name": "Quote",
        "settings": [
          {
            "id": "content",
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Quote"
          },
          {
            "id": "title",
            "type": "text",
            "label": "Title"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
{% endschema %}
```

So to summarize you need to learn the difference between a `settings_schema.json` syntax and the section `{% schema %}` syntax.

At the moment I'm not sure if you are making your options inside the `settings_schema.json` or you are making a separate section. In both cases you need to fix the schema syntax.

If you are using the `settings_schema.json` there is no `{% schema %}` around the json.

If you are using a section `{% schema %}` you are allowed for only one object (if it's not a block):

```
{
    "name": "Main Menu",
    "settings": [
     .....
    ]
}
```

Read the section docs: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/sections

And the settings_schema docs: https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/theme-editor/settings-schema